# ReferenceError: 'updated-on' is not defined<br>

Tags: json, express

I am unable to get key from json object in express js.the key is composed

> updated-by

it is showing my error like "ReferenceError: 'on' is not defined
"

Comment: Could you please post the code wherein you are trying to get the key from the json object?

Comment: Please look into the code below
result['Configuration']['MacIdList'][0]['mac'][request.body.id].activated-on = request.body.data.activatedOn;
result['Configuration']['MacIdList'][0]['mac'][request.body.id].activated-by = request.body.data.activatedBy;
result['Configuration']['MacIdList'][0]['mac'][request.body.id].deactivated-on = request.body.data.deactivatedOn;